# Out of bounds exception in double dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, double, dimensional

Trying to find the sum of all even numbers and product of all odd numbers in a double dimensional array.

Why am I getting the following out of bounds exception error ?

```
Exception java. lang. Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception
```

While running the code this exception comes for line `if(m[i][j]%2==0)`

[image: photo of code]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Because when i=1 and j=4, the index doesn't exist in your array.

Answer (score 2):

The exact cause of your error is that your 2D array is actually a *jagged* array, meaning that not every row contains the same number of elements.  In fact, the second row only contains three elements, so when you when the following `if` check:

```
if (m[i][j]%2 == 0)
```

you get an out of bounds exception for `i=1` and `j=3`.

You should either make the 2D array non-jagged, or instead use this `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j < m[i].length; ++j) {
            if (m[i][j]%2 == 0) {
                s += m[i][j];
            }
            else {
                r *= m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason I am getting the result zero for variable r , is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @JohnDoe that's a different problem. The reason is that you're initializing `r = 0`, so no matter what value you multiply it by, the result will always be `0`. i.e.: `0 * 23 = 0`, right?

Comment: the program is now working successfully thanks for your timely help

Answer (score 1):

Your `m` array's element at index `1` is missing a fourth element:

```
{30,11,71}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do not** use as limits **fixed values** (such as `4`), but instead **use** the **`length`** provided by the array(s).

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
      //...
    }
}
```

**Why?**

Not all inner arrays have 4 elements (i.e.: `{30, 11, 71}`), so at the last iteration of the inner loop (`j = 3`), this code `m[i][j]` tries to access a value out of the bounds of the array because in some cases there is no position `3`, just `0` (1st element), `1`(2nd element) and `2`(3rd element). Thus you get the mentioned exception.

*Side note*:

Another problem ([mentioned by you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667675/out-of-bounds-exception-in-double-dimensional-array/56667741#comment99903988_56667741)) is that you will get `r = 0` always because it is initialized to `0` and every time you multiply its value by another one, the result will be `0`.

So, in order to fix this you need to add a check in the `else` condition, like this:

```
else {
    r = r == 0 ? m[i][j] : r * m[i][j];
}
```

Comment: @JohnDoe it's great you got it working now! Consider to mark an answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so future readers know the problem was solved.